# Select distinct multiple columns with one result column in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I would like execute below in Redshift. It can be handled in Postgrsql using unnest but not working in Redshift

Actually I have rows like

```
id  col_a  col_b  col_c
1   ABD    CDE    XYZ
2   CDE    null   null
3   ABD    null   null
3   FGH    LMN   null
```

And I expect as a result

```
ABC
ABD
CDE
FGH
LMN
XYZ
```

Comment: @Blanko please do not tag questions that are exclusively for Redshift with `postgresql`. Although they share some ancient roots the two products are sufficiently different

Answer (score 3):

With `UNION` for each of the columns, to get the distinct values:

```
select col_a as col from tablename
where col_a is not null
union
select col_b from tablename
where col_b is not null
union
select col_c from tablename
where col_c is not null
order by col
```

Comment: Thanks forpas, I'm looking effective solution other than UNION. Is there any other way?

Comment: Unless Redshift has any special way of doing this (which I'm not aware of) you have to use UNION.